# How do I copy the URL contained in the internet shortcut in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, internet-connection, shortcuts, url

Sometimes my Internet shortcut doesn't work properly when I double-click on it.

Is there a way to easily copy the URL contained in the shortcut for Windows 7.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work properly"?

Comment: Are you asking about Internet shortcuts or keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean a desktop or folder-stored link to a URL, right-click and choose Properties. The URL will already be highlighted for you, so all you have to do is copy it (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and then paste in the address bar of your favorite browser.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the link and select 'copy Link Address'; then paste it in the address bar.