# How do I copy the URL contained in the Internet shortcut?

Tags: windows-explorer, clipboard, url

I saw [an answer to this question in a post already](https://superuser.com/a/655762/167207) but I am wanting to know if there is a way to do multiple files at one time versus clicking on each shortcut file individually to get the URL?  I just need to get the URLs to the clipboard so I can paste in Excel and I have hundreds of these shortcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this at the command prompt from the top level directory containing all your .URL files, and you should end up with URLs.txt as well as (on Windows 7 onwards) the URLs copied to the clipboard:

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %a in ('findstr /s /l "URL=" *.url') do @echo %b>>URLs.txt && clip<URLs.txt
```

Comment: It took me a while and some help from our local IT but we got this to work.  It's just what I needed, thanks!!!

Comment: Glad I could help. :)