# How do I copy the URL contained in the Internet shortcut with unicode characters? (command line for many Internet shorcuts)

Tags: windows, command-line, unicode, url

The subject was in part studied, there is 8 years (here : [How do I copy the URL contained in the Internet shortcut?](https://superuser.com/questions/899312/how-do-i-copy-the-url-contained-in-the-internet-shortcut?newreg=333df7021e584362aa9b9eb5f7c8b86b))

I have thousand Internet shortcuts that I would like copy the URL contained to txt file.

I have used the command line (with Win + R , CMD), suggested by Karan :
it's all right !

BUT :-( ,
it doesn't work with Internet shorcuts witch name contains french characters (eg. é ù î à) or Chineese characters (eg. 中 太 国).
Or I am french and I practice Taijiquan… *[**Note added after having edited :** in fact, for french characters (é ù î à…) : no problem, see PPS.]*
That why mainly of my Internet shortcuts contains these characters, so I don't know the solution…

Thank you very much for your attention, and if you have an idea to solve my problem (with command line method, or other method (?))… It would be wonderful because I have this question since many years…

For information :

- I use Win 10 and my level in informatic is very light and basic
- The link suggested by Jimadine (http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/183436) is broken (and seems not saved on http://web.archive.org)

Friendships to all !

PS :

1. Example of folder with Internet shortcuts :
   [image]
2. The result of DOS command :
   [image]
3. And the txt file obtained :
   [image]
4. Observation :
   Looking more precisly the result, I see that sometimes URL which name contents accents obtain a correct result in txt file… So, I am very perplex !
   Here URL which have failed :
   https://www.lepoint.fr/sport/les-essentiels-du-yoga-1-la-posture-de-l-enfant-21-09-2019-2336989_26.php
   https://www.lepoint.fr/sport/les-essentiels-du-yoga-9-la-torsion-au-sol-16-11-2019-2347753_26.php
   https://www.lepoint.fr/sport/les-essentiels-du-yoga-13-la-posture-de-l-enfant-retourne-14-12-2019-2353171_26.php
   https://www.lepoint.fr/sport/les-essentiels-du-yoga-16-la-posture-de-l-aigle-04-01-2020-2356139_26.php
   https://www.lepoint.fr/sport/les-essentiels-du-yoga-17-la-posture-de-la-pyramide-11-01-2020-2357301_26.php
   https://www.lepoint.fr/sport/les-essentiels-du-yoga-18-la-posture-de-la-tete-de-vache-18-01-2020-2358428_26.php
   https://www.lepoint.fr/sport/les-essentiels-du-yoga-19-la-posture-du-demi-grand-ecart-25-01-2020-2359619_26.php
   https://www.lepoint.fr/sport/les-essentiels-du-yoga-20-la-posture-de-la-fente-basse-01-02-2020-2360806_26.php
   https://www.lepoint.fr/sport/les-essentiels-du-yoga-21-tonifier-ses-abdominaux-08-02-2020-2361793_26.php
   https://www.lepoint.fr/sport/les-essentiels-du-yoga-22-la-respiration-carree-15-02-2020-2362865_26.php
5. About example with Chineese characters :
   Name of Internet shortcut : 中国太極文化学院
   URL : https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCRQzrSQweuWQ9FPaBpZkfjQ

PPS :
After new examination :
About 'french accents' (as é ù î à) : they were not at the origin of the problem : the fail came from the unicode character U+2013 (–) (named "En Dash").
So I have modified the Title of my post, to centrate my question on chineese characters, and unicode characters more generaly…

Comment: Can you give some example urls for people to test with? What does your text file end up looking like? You may end up having to pass your urls through something like https://onlinetools.com/unicode/url-encode-unicode and if that works then it may be that we can find a command line method that achieve similar.

Comment: Try a different notepad program. For example Notepad++ supports UTF8. I bet it works perfectly there.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: @ Mokubai
1) I have edited my post and added exemples in a PS.

Comment: @ Mokubai
2) I use Windows 10

Comment: Dunno if it’s the source of the problem, but I strongly suggest not using Command Prompt for anything that could involve different charsets and/or unicode.

Comment: @LPChip : I'm not sure to understand… To use Notepad++ to open URLs.txt (file created by command line) ? If yes, the problem doesn't seem to come from here, but to come from DOS emulator and the command line (see screenshot : "FINDSTR :  Impossible to open […].url")

Comment: @ Mokubai 
I have tried your suggestion for the Internet shortcut named 中国太極文化学院 : https://onlinetools.com/unicode/url-encode-unicode gives : %e4%b8%ad%e5%9b%bd%e5%a4%aa%e6%a5%b5%e6%96%87%e5%8c%96%e5%ad%a6%e9%99%a2 So I have tried to rename the Internet shortcut (named 中国太極文化学院) by this new name (ie %e4%b8%ad%e5%9b%bd%e5%a4%aa%e6%a5%b5%e6%96%87%e5%8c%96%e5%ad%a6%e9%99%a2). Result : dos emulator and command line gives the correct result (ie https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCRQzrSQweuWQ9FPaBpZkfjQ) ! We seem to be on the good way ! Yes ! :-)

Comment: Ah, I understand what you're after now. You are using a .cmd script, and if the codepage is not set correctly, UTF-8 will not work or wrongly. May I suggest to transform this into a Powershell script, where UTF-8 is natively supported?

Comment: To LPChip : I am unfortunately not able to produce this transformation… The DOS emulator command is [I have not writen it, but only found it on Internet] :      for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %a in ('findstr /s /l "URL=" *.url') do @echo %b>>URLs.txt && clip<URLs.txt                 If anyone has an suggestion for this transformation ???

Comment: @ Mokubai (a)  : I have used your excellent suggested site (https://onlinetools.com/unicode/url-encode-unicode) to transform (manually, one by one) all the names of the other Internet shortcuts failed (eg "Les essentiels du yoga #9 – La torsion au sol lepoint.fr Actualité Sports VIDÉO. Professeure de yoga, Masha Kruglova vous co" into "Les essentiels du yoga %239 %e2%80%93 La torsion au sol lepoint.fr Actualit%c3%a9 Sports VID%c3%89O. Professeure de yoga%2c Masha Kruglova vous co"). That's OK ! you were perfectly right : now I obtain a txt file with the correct URL !

Comment: @ Makubai (b) :  So, may it be that someone could find a command line method that achieve similar ? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be that DOS does not like the unicode in your URL filenames.

A powershell alternative to your DOS command (that should be unicode-safe) and works on my machine using a couple of your example URLs:

```
foreach ($url in Get-ChildItem *.url) {
    get-content $url -ReadCount 1000 | foreach { $_ -match "URL=" -replace "URL=",""} | Out-File -append urls.txt
}
```

The results of running that code in powershell:

[image]

Comment: @ Mokubai : Excellent ! It's perfect ! It works on my machine with all shortcuts tried. Thank you very much for your invaluable help. I was researching this solution on Internet since five years… A note for people interested : to go to Power Shell :  Windows logo key + X. Then, place your Internet Shorcuts in "Folder_Shorcuts" on C: And to finish, write "cd c:\Folder_Shorcuts" in Power Shell command line.

Comment: @dglr glad it works for you.